# Can PHP bind a list of numbers in a SQL prepared statement?

Tags: php, coldfusion

I am converting a Coldfusion website to PHP.  I have a query that looks in a list of comma separated numbers to see if there is a match and then responds accordingly.  This is the where statement I am currently using.

```
WHERE (`link_issue_category`.`Category_ID` IN (<CFQUERYPARAM value="#Category_id#" list = "yes">)
```

How do I write this in PHP?

Comment: php? looks like a mysql db query to me

Comment: It would help if you told the people who know PHP but not ColdFusion what the ColdFusion code is supposed to do.

Comment: @rid `category_id` is a comma delimitted list of IDs. Just like he states in his question

Comment: @MattBusche, so `<CFQUERYPARAM value="#Category_id#" list = "yes">` is a... string variable containing a... SQL escaped, comma delimited list of... numbers?

Comment: @rid correct. It's just like saying `IN (#Category_id#)` or `IN (1,2,3,4)` the `cfqueryparam` is used to prevent SQL injection

Comment: The query is nested in a loop query.  The Category ID of an issue record is matched with an ID that may appear in a list of comma separated category IDs a user selected in their preferences preferences.

Answer (score 0):

CFQUERYPARAM does some validation on the value, and if possible sets up a bind parameter. You can probably just embed the value into the SQL, assuming you've already done validation / sanitization on it. The list parameter specifies that this is a comma-delimited list. You should be able to plug this list directly into the query, depending on the value type.

```
"WHERE (`link_issue_category`.`Category_ID` IN ($category_id)";
```

If your values in the list are strings, you may need to wrap them in qoutes before they go into the query.

Comment: Doesn't php have something called prepared statements that are more or less equivalent to using query parameters?

Answer (score 0):

FYI CF just creates a new prepared statement with the number of `?` being the same as the length of your list behind the scene.

So if you want the same behaviour in PHP, it wouldn't be that hard really.  Just dynamically create a new prepared statement, and bind them accordingly.

PHP Prepared statements: http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php

However, you could have just use regex to validate the list of values to numeric value and comma's only, and use the variable as part of the SQL statement.